# Возможность захвата и стриминга экрана в iOS: ограничения, возможности и публикация приложения в AppStore

Tags: ios, iphone, appstore, webrtc, remote

Как в ios дела состоят с захватом и стримингом экрана/передачей на экран движений с другого телефона. Спрашивал у gpt, он говорит что очень жёсткие правило по поводу этого, но это возможно. Почему тогда в айфоне в rustDesk нельзя транслировать экран и почему нету TeamViewer Host под айфон?
Возможно ли реализовать такое приложение и опубликовать его потом в AppStore?

Answer (score 0):

Стриминг экрана возможен точно, потому что существуют такие приложения как StreamLabs например. Оно позволяет захватывать изображение с экрана и передавать его по сети. Что касается управления устройством, то тут возникают большие вопросы.

В iOS 16 Купертиновцы сделали первый шаг, к тому, чтобы управлять своими устройствами удаленно. И сильно сомневаюсь что теперь пустят в стор, приложения со схожим функционалом.

Но а так как подобных приложений не было и до этого, то скорее всего есть ограничения со стороны безопасности которые не позволяют этого делать.

Comment: Например будет 2 устройства A (которое принимает поток данных) и B (отправляет поток данных)
Если у меня на A устройстве будут слушатся нажатия по стриму с устройства B и по сокетам будут передаватся координаты нажатий на устройство В и там эмулироватся (перед всей этой схемой естественно будет модалка с запросом на разрешение к доступу), то будет ли это считатся опасной схемой из-за которой могут не пустить в стор?
Я прочекал https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/ и там вроде нету пунктов про ограничение на remote control и я тогда не понимаю почему нету похожих аналогов